# Read/Write datetime to DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to write/read the date and time from the DB table. When I log in to my page, I wnat to read the saved date and time and when I logout I want to write to the DB the curent date and time, so When I login next time, to read the last login date and time. I stored a date format like this in the DB table "2014-09-12 14:48:30" but my code is not even read from it..

```
$login_event = mysql_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(events, '%M %D, %Y') AS mydate FROM login_events WHERE name = $login_name");
echo $login_name;
```

Please if someone can help me out on this I will be very grateful!

Comment: how do you know it is not reading it?  all you are echoing is the login_name.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$login_event = mysql_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(events, '%M %D, %Y') AS mydate FROM login_events WHERE name = '$login_name'");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($login_event);

echo $row['mydate'];
```

Comment: thank you very much for the suggestions, but it give me the `mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL` error...

Comment: thank you!! working like a charm! only a little think, it's display only the date... the time is not displayed...

Comment: Then you need to put some more arguments ad the second parameter in DATE_FORMAT. I guess you'll wand something like  ... **DATE_FORMAT(events,'%M %D, %Y %T')** ...

Comment: yes, thank you! Now it's displayed correctly! And when I log out, how to udpate this date and time on the DB table?

Comment: when you logout, on logout PHP perform an UPDATE query and set events = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') (this is php code) where name='$login_name'

Comment: I try this code, but is not updating: `mysql_query("UPDATE $tablename SET events = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') WHERE name = '$login_name'");` do you have any suggestion?

Comment: mysql_query("UPDATE $tablename SET events = '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') ."' WHERE name = '$login_name'");

Comment: yes, you tell me that is a PHP code... sorry. It's working now! Thank you very much for your help! Only one last thing, I don't know what time zone is used, because is with 2 housr behind from my time?!

Comment: no problem! I resolved! the code is `date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");` Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You have your `mysql_query()` syntax wrong, check here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_query.asp (unless you just rewrote it from head).

Plus you have to fetch the array: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_fetch_array.asp

```
$result = mysql_fetch_array($login_event);
echo $result["mydate"];
```